# change value in custom_preinitializers baed on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change the value in custom preinitializers based on hour of time,for that i have written a proc for this purpose

```
DUTATION = Proc.new do
  if Time.zone.now.hour >= 9 && Time.zone.now.hour <= 17
    AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:day]
  else
    AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:night]
  end
end
```

but this does not work i tried it using it in the routes.rb as

```
DUTATION  = Proc.new do
  if Time.zone.now.hour >= 9 && Time.zone.now.hour <= 17
    AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:day]
  else
    AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:night]
  end
end
```

but this give me error as but works and log files is filled with errors and server crashed

```
warning: previous definition of DUTATION was here
warning: already initialized constant DUTATION
```

if i change it to:

```
 DUTATION  ||= Proc.new do
   if Time.zone.now.hour >= 9 && Time.zone.now.hour <= 17
     AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:day]
   else
     AVAILABLE_DUTATION[:night]
   end
 end
```

in routes then it does not work but error message does not appear.

ultimately i have too use this in routes as

```
match 'duration' => "=users##{DUTATION.call}", via: [:get, :post]
```

but all the methods i have tried does not seem to work. please suggest some suitable method for this. i am on rails 4.2.8 and ruby 2.3.4

Comment: Is the goal to route a particular request to a controller#action based on the current time?

Comment: are you sure your DURATION.call proc fires on each request, or just once when rails is loaded(or file changed in dev mode) ?

Comment: yes based on time.

Comment: it fires for each request